# How can I change a custom date into numbers in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to do a vlookup/sumif based on dates
How can I do it? I saw from a source I have to first change it into numbers
Somehow I cannot do it with formulas like value/Datevalue, I can only convert it by changing its format.

Spreadsheet image

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vlookup()` and `sumif()` functions work fine with dates and date time values.

With `vlookup()`, you can get an exact match of a date time value by setting the `is_sorted` parameter to `false`. To match the first value that is less than or equal to a date time, make sure that the data range is sorted, and set that parameter to `true`.

With `sumif()`, if you need to remove the time component from a date time value to match dates to date times, use `datevalue()`.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how dates and times work in spreadsheets.